# RSPEC results appended to just 1 file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Whenever I run several Spec files, it overwrites the previous results file. How can I run several spec files with the results appended to just 1 file. I have the following configuration:

```
require 'etc'
require 'yarjuf'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.color=true
  config.add_formatter(:documentation)
  config.add_formatter(JUnit,"./results/rspec_results.xml")
end
```

And I just call the specfiles as:

```
$ bundle exec rspec basic1_spec.rb
$ bundle exec rspec basic2_spec.rb
```

I need to have the results of both basic1 and basic2 in the same file 'rspec_results.xml'

**NOTE: I don't want to do "bundle exec rspec *spec.rb"** => since I run the spec files individually sometimes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass multiple filenames to `rspec`:

```
$ bundle exec rspec basic1_spec.rb basic2_spec.rb
```

Comment: Would this execute the files in the order of the arguments? Anyway, thanks so much for this answer.

Comment: Yes, by default `rspec` will read and execute spec files in the order they're given. You can change this behavior using the `--order` option: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/order

Comment: Just a note: the order of execution of spec files is not by order of the spec files given on the command line. 
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/1900
One workaround I got working is alphabetically naming the spec files to determine the order.

Answer (score 0):

You could try also with:

```
$ bundle exec rspec basic1_spec.rb >> file.xml
$ bundle exec rspec basic2_spec.rb >> file.xml
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but got this error - C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:251:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_s
ysopen - ./results/rspec_results.xml (Errno::EACCES) 

Any reason why I'm getting Permission error? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the right permission to write in the path that you have specified? It seems that you don't have the ownership of the folder.

Comment: Is this for shell? Or would this work on a windows CMD prompt? I am using windows at the moment (yeah, it's a nightmare), because of system requirements.